# HQL wildcard with Hibernate UserType

Tags: hibernate, usertype

I have created Hibernate UserType for my PhoneNumber class backed by single VARCHAR column in db. Generally it works fine. But now I need something like this

```
String hql = "FROM Call c WHERE c.calledNumber LIKE :param";
...
query.setParameter("param", "%385%");
```

which ends with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%385%] did not match expected type [PhoneNumber]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`c.calledNumber` is a `PhoneNumber` object and you're trying to compare it with a string `'%385%'`. What's happening is like comparing a table to a column.

What you should do write is this:

`String QUERY = "FROM Call c join c.calledNumber pn WHERE pn.number LIKE :myNumber"`;

where `pn.number` field is a java string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String hql = "FROM Call c WHERE c.calledNumber LIKE concat('%', :param, '%')";
...
query.setParameter("param", "385");
```

will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Parameters inside string literals are not resolved.

You need to add %s to parameter values with string concatenation.

You could try:

```
String QUERY = "FROM Call c WHERE c.calledNumber LIKE :myNumber";
(List<Call>)session.createQuery(QUERY)
    .setString("myNumber", "%" + "385" + "%").list();
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake while simplifying example. I updated the question, it should be correct now.